# Recover partition from NTFS drive with folder structure

Tags: external-disk, folders, data-recovery, ntfs

I ran disk utility and looked for errors on a NTFS drive that was working fine but had been ejected abruptly after the computer was forced to shut down. After that a bunch of errors just appeared in red and the disk became "empty". The only folder available is named "found.000" and cannot be opened.

I have been able to recover data from the disk with Data Rescue but the folder structure is not there. I have a bunch of folders like MP3 1, MP3 2, Documents etc. containing the files with the corresponding format and some have even been renamed.

I ran Test Disk and the geometry of the disk seems to be wrong but I do not dare to deal with it because I do not know Test Disk really well and I cannot find many information about head/cylinder numbers etc.

Is there any software that allows mac users to retrieve data with folder structure?

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8

This is the Test Disk log :

```
Disk /dev/rdisk2 - 500 GB / 465 GiB - 976773168 sectors (RO)                    
Current partition structure:                                                    
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors             

Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 255 (NTFS) != 1 (HD)               
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 63 (NTFS) != 1 (HD)             
 1 P HPFS - NTFS                 2048  976771119  976769072 [TOSHIBA EXT]       

Warning: Bad starting sector (CHS and LBA don't match)                          
No partition is bootable                                                        

0 D FAT32 715093261 1896786745 1181693485 
FAT32 715093261 1896786745 1181693485 
check_FAT: can't read FAT boot sector 
Invalid FAT boot sector 
0 D FAT16 LBA 2125262773 5909813675 3784550903 
FAT16 LBA 2125262773 5909813675 3784550903 
check_FAT: can't read FAT boot sector 
Invalid FAT boot sector 
0 D FAT32 LBA 1365415759 2816414404 1450998646 
FAT32 LBA 1365415759 2816414404 1450998646 
check_FAT: can't read FAT boot sector 
Invalid FAT boot sector 
0 D FAT12 2873871126 2963834879 89963754 
FAT12 2873871126 2963834879 89963754
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but future readers might be interested in a Python program that runs on Linux and Mac as well. See [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](http://askubuntu.com/q/775579/271).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but future readers might be interested in a Python program that runs on Linux and Mac as well. See [http://askubuntu.com/q/775579/271](http://askubuntu.com/q/775579/271).